# Задача извлечения цифры из позиции числа (Java)

Tags: java

Приветствую всех!

Собственно вот задача ...

Есть целое(int) число: например **251**.

**Необходимо оставить цифру, которая находится только на первой позиции этого числа, остальные отбросить.**

Пример:

- исходное число: **251** ---> получаемое число: **1**
- исходное число: **1912** ---> получаемое число: **2**
- исходное число: **19** ---> получаемое число: **9**

---

Вопрос. Какие способы реализуемы ? И есть ли в арсенале побитовые операции для этого ?

Comment: Зачем побитовые операции если есть `% 10` ?

Comment: Да спасибо! это универсальный способ! как же я его упустил из внимания :( 
Про побитовость - чисто спортивный интерес появился... некоторые интересные трюки из книжки "Алгоритмические трюки для программстов" понравились, но для такой операции пока не нашел там

Comment: Маловероятно, что получится добиться того же эффекта с помощью побитовых операций в принципе: сдвиги умножают или делят число на 2, любое отдельное изменение бита прибавляет или убавляет на 2^n... Добиться из этого остатка от деления на 10 сложно :)

Comment: Так на первой позиции или, всё же, на последней?

Comment: Пусть будет первый разряд - так точнее)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используй операцию получение остатка от деления(%) на 10

```
System.out.println(19 % 10);//результат 9
System.out.println(251 % 10);//результат 1
System.out.println(1912 % 10);//результат 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.print(x%10); /Остаток от деления на 10
```